# Generate all disjoint covers from the power set

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics

Given a set $S$, I would like to enumerate all sets of the form $P = \{P_{1}, ..., P_{n}\}$ with a fixed $n \leq \left\vert{S}\right\vert$ such that $\bigcup P_{i} = S$ and $i \neq j \implies P_{i} \cap P_{j} = \varnothing$.

(I read a little bit about the set covering problem, but choosing disjoint covers from the power set of $S$ seemed to be different enough that it wasn’t directly applicable.)

Intuitively, this seems to me to be equivalent to computing all the permutations of $S$ and then placing $n - 1$ cuts in every possible way in each permutation. I think that gives ${{(\left\vert{S}\right\vert + n - 1)!}\over{(n - 1)!}}$ possibilities for $P$. However, I’d like to find something more convincing than my intuition.

Comment: Must all the parts $P_i$ be non-empty? If so, the answer is Stirling numbers of the second kind.

Comment: The numbers Yuval suggests will count the number of partitions of $S$ into nonempty sets, but you can adapt it to enumerate the partitions by adjusting the recursion used to calculate Stirling numbers of the second kind instead.

Comment: Thank you @D.W.—I have taken your advice and flagged the question.